# DOM Navigation - Previous Sibling undefined

Tags: javascript, dom, traversal

I am attempting to get the Element Value "blah blah blah" from the `<p>` on a button click of the "share-button". The content is dynamically created so it need to be from the button element.

```
<div class="cd-timeline-content">
    <h2 id="title">title</h2>
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
    <a class="cd-read-more">Read more</a>
    <button id="share_button" type="button" class="share btn btn-default"></button>
     <span class="cd-date"></span>  
</div>
```

I have tried the below but It doesn't seem to works.

```
var btn = $('#share_button')
var caption = btn.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
```

Comment: `btn` is a jQuery object not a Dom object. Try `btn.prev()` or `btn[0]` to access the DOM element

Answer (score 0):

If there is going to be only one `<p>` element inside `<div class="cd-timeline-content">` I would suggest:

```
btn.closest('.cd-timeline-content').find('p').html();
```